# Put and retrieve scripts/variable Laravel database

Tags: mysql, laravel

Im trying to retrieve this data but I get same output variable are not change
[image]

Im trying also change this `$name` to `{{ name }} / {!! name !!}` but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're keeping it as a string, you need to parse it first:

```
$string = str_replace('$name', $name, $string);
```